# how to add constraint with columns in external tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

An easy way to explain my problem is this: 
I want to create a table that will contain the information about the subjects that will be dictated in a school. The columns must be:

```
create table program( teacher varchar(20) references teachers(name), 
                          classroom  varchar(20) references classrooms(id),
                          dtime datetime)
```

In each one of the tables `teachers` and `classrooms` exists a column named 'subject', corresponding to the subject that is dictated by a teacher and the subject that is taught in a classroom (imagine there's no more columns in those tables).

Now, I want to create a constraint in the `program` table that doesn't let me insert a row where the subject dictated in the classroom is different from the subject dictated by the teacher.

Comment: Don't use the "mysql" tag for questions about sql server.

Comment: @Kadriand You will need a subject column in the program table to enforce the rules with a foreign key constraint.

Comment: I don't think you could do that without  de-normalizing your table structures. You will have to check `If Exists` rows in the other tables (`teacher` and `classroom`) before inserting into the`program` table.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use composite foreign keys.  This is going to be simplest by putting the `subjectId` in the `programs table`.  Here is the example for teachers:

```
create table teachers (
    teacherid int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    name varchar(255) not null,
    subjectid int references subjects(subjectid),
    unique (teacherid, subjectid)
);

create table programs (
    programid int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    teacherid int references teachers(teacherid), 
    classroomid int references classrooms(classroomid),
    dtime datetime
    subjectid int references subjects(subjectid),
    foreign key (teacherid, subjectid) references teachers(teacherid, subjectid),
    foreign key (classroomid, subjectid) references classrooms(classroomid, subjecdtid)
);
```

If you don't put the subject in the `programs` table, then you will need to use a user defined function for the constraint.  This seems like a simpler solution.